# Date conversion - ISO?

Tags: sql, date, db2

I was given this line to add to my query from a co-worker but I'm not understanding what it is doing. Unfortunately he is offline and on vacation so I couldn't ask him directly. I ran the query with and without this line and I don't see the difference.

```
g.fromdos > replace(char(current date - 10 days, iso), '-', '')
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that, DB2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making educated guesses, since the DBMS is not specified:

- The `current date - 10 days` produces the date 10 days ago.
- The `char(current date - 10 days, iso)` formats the date in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which looks like "2014-12-13" (given that today is 2014-12-23).
- The replace operation replaces the dashes with nothing, yielding "20141213".
- So, the comparison checks whether the `g.fromdos` value compares larger than "20141213".

Without knowledge of the type of `g.fromdos`, it's not possible to say whether the comparison is done as numbers or strings.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, the part that I did not understand was the iso note. Thanks again!